# Ending scanf after wrong input C

Tags: c

im trying to make C calculator app. That means there is input "x + y =" and i need to calculate the result. My problem is when user input for example "6 + 4". That means there is missing equals sign. But the program is waiting for more data. How to block scanf waiting for more data after pressing enter and just say that this input was wrong?

```
double x,y;
char c;      //this desires if its plus, minus ...
if(scanf("%lf %c %lf =",&x,&c,&y)!=3)
{
    printf("wrong input\n");
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: How about reading an entire line first using `fgets()`, and then parsing it using `sscanf()`?

Comment: You cannot use `scanf` for unpredictable input. You need to use `fgets` and then parse the line yourself, possibly with `sscanf`

Answer (score 1):

> How to block scanf waiting for more data after pressing enter and just say that this input was wrong?

And then what to do with that bad/partially read  input?  Leave it for the next `scanf()`?  `scanf()` simple does not readily handle unpredictably input [@Jabberwocky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64354118/ending-scanf-after-wrong-input-c/64354311#comment113797309_64354118).

A robust approach is to read a *line* with `fgets()`, then parse it.

Code could use `sscanf()` and `"%n"`, which records the scan offset, to see if scanning made it that far.

```
  char buf[100];
  if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) {
    int n = 0;
    sscanf(buf, "%lf %c %lf = %n", &x, &c, &y, &n);
    if (n == 0 || buf[n] != '\0') {
      printf("Bad input <%s>\n", buf);
    } else {
      printf("Oh happy day! <%s>\n", buf);
    }
  }
```

More advanced code would cope with lines longer than 100 and use `strtod()` to parse `double`.